# How to pass-in IMongoFields values into a function parameter

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

say i write a function:

```
public static List<BsonDocument> MyFind(string collection, IMongoQuery query, IMongoSortBy sort, int skip)
{ ..etc..}
```

easily i can pass-in values like:

```
list = MyFind("collectionname",Query.EQ("field","value"),SortBy.Ascending("field"), 0).ToList()
```

but what if i add another parameter on the function: IMongoFields fields, so the function would look like:

```
public static List<BsonDocument> MyFind(string collection, IMongoQuery query, IMongoFields fields, IMongoSortBy sort, int skip)
{ ..etc..}
```

i'm having problems passing in values for the "fields". i've read MongoDB driver documentation, but can't imagine really how to pass the values in. is there some way to build the field names similar to what you do with a List?

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the fluent static class Fields that returns IMongoFields:

```
 MyFind("collectionName", Query.EQ("field", "value"),
               Fields.Include("field_a", "field_b").Exclude("excluded_field"), 
               SortBy.Null, 1);
```

Don't forge to include the namespace:

```
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;
```